# Регулярные выражения, как сделать отсечку точка+пробел (2 символа)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, hive

Всем привет

Вот пример моего текста `Тест kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj7. 87sf8sf`.
Я хочу, чтобы моё регулярное выражение выдавало мне `s.test.ru/g/dskj7`.

Здесь `kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf` получаем `s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf` Здесь `kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj78. 7sf8sf` получаем `s.test.ru/g/dskj78` Здесь `kssc://s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf test` получаем `s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf`

Я пишу его так `(?i)kssc\w*://([^.\s]+)`
Но оно возвращает мне только `s`

Как мне исправить его, чтобы останавливаться именно на `.`  символах точка + пробел?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
(?<=kssc:\/\/)(?:(?!\.?\s).)*
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5adnl

> Тест kssc://**s.test.ru/g/dskj7**. 87sf8sf
>
> 234123 kssc://**s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf**
>
> kssc://**s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf**
>
> kssc://**s.test.ru/g/dskj78**. 7sf8sf
>
> kssc://**s.test.ru/g/dskj787sf8sf** test

Comment: Та за шо минус?